# объясните что такое this в js

Tags: javascript

Объясните пожалуйста мне, недалёкому *быдлокодеру*, **что такое this в JS**, для чего оно нужно, где используется, желательно привести пару примеров, потому что я не понимаю принцип работы, когда я читаю об этом на информационных ресурсах.

[первый ресурс](https://tproger.ru/translations/javascript-cheatsheet/#varconstlet)

[второй ресурс](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: ссылка на текущий объект; если нет объекта то на глобальный объект window ; если в новом стандарте то будет undefined

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods#ssylochnyy-tip здесь

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/149516/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кратко, то в `JS this` — это текущий контекст исполнения функции.
Если метод был вызван из объекта, тогда `this` в контексте метода является ссылкой на родительский объект:

```js
var parent = {
  method: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

parent.method();

//А при таком вызове будет ссылаться на Window:

var parentless = parent.method;

parentless();
```

Comment: и для чего это нужно в итоге, в случае с ссылкой на родительский объект?

Comment: Например, чтобы организовать выполнение функции в зависимости от контекста, в котором она вызвана. В частности, в зависимости от родительского объекта ее поведение может быть разным.

Comment: @СотниЛичностей советую почитать что-нибудь про ООП вне рамок javascript, а именно, понять, что такое классы, методы и экземпляры классов. Тогда вам сразу станет понятно, зачем нужен this.